# Optimization of the ternary operator in Perl

Tags: perl, loops, optimization, ternary-operator

I have this loop :

```
for my $line (split /\n/, $content) {
    ($line !~ /^\-{2,}$/) ? ( $return .= "$line\n" )
                          : ( $return .= "\N{ZERO WIDTH SPACE}$line\n" );
}
```

There will be mostly lines that doesn't match the regex (ie : most of the time the condition will be true).

I've first wrote the condition using the `=~` operator (with the two conditional instructions swapped) but then this is the **second** instruction would have been executed most of the times.

In other words… When you have a test which you know that it will choose one branch in 99% of the cases, does it change something (performance) to write it with that branch first?

Comment: Those parens are unnecessary, they make it look like something more is going on. It's easier to read without them.

Comment: Presumably you have read the entirety of a file into `$content` by altering `$/`? If so then you may as well just leave `$/`as it is and read the file line by line. That also has the advantage that you don't need to add a newline back to the end of each output line.

Comment: A hyphen `-` in a regex pattern doesn't need to be escaped.

Comment: my $re = qr/^-{2,}$/o; my $return = join "\n", map { $_ = "\N{ZERO WIDTH SPACE}".$_ if $_ =~ $re; } split(/\n/, $content);

Comment: Please don't use the ternary operator as an alternative way to write `if`. The operator returns a value, so use it! `$return .= expr ? "$line\n" : "\N{ZERO WIDTH SPACE}$line\n";`

Comment: @oals, yes this is what I did, as Schwern suggested.

Comment: In lower-level languages, there can be a difference because of CPU cache misses. But with heavy languages like Perl, that's no longer a factor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *When you have a test which you know that it will choose one branch in 99% of the cases, does it change something (performance) to write it with that branch first?*

In the simple if/else case (which is what the ternary operator is), the answer is ***no***. The order of the branches does not matter, the condition will run every time and pick which branch to go down.

In an if/elsif/else case it would matter because there are multiple conditionals to be run. Putting the most common case first would make things faster.

If an if/else pick the order that makes the most sense for the reader, and that usually means avoiding negatives. `$line =~ /^\-{2,}$/` is easier to read than `$line !~ /^\-{2,}$/`. `$line =~ /^-{2,}$/` is even better (there's no need to escape `-` in a regex).

At least it *shouldn't matter*. As with anything as complicated as Perl, it's best to benchmark these things. It's a bit troublesome to come up with something that will exercise the CPU enough so as not to be lost in the normal benchmarking jitter. Be sure to run this multiple times with plenty of iterations before drawing conclusions.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

use Benchmark qw(cmpthese);

my $Iterations = shift;

my $Threshhold = 100_000;

# I've picked something that isn't constant to avoid constant folding
sub a_then_b {
    my $num = shift;
    return $num > $Threshhold ? sqrt($num) + sqrt($num) ** 2
                              : $num + $num;
}

sub b_then_a {
    my $num = shift;
    return $num <= $Threshhold ? $num + $num
                               : sqrt($num) + sqrt($num) ** 2;
}

say "First one side";
cmpthese $Iterations, {
    a_then_b => sub { a_then_b($Threshhold - 1) },
    b_then_a => sub { b_then_a($Threshhold - 1) }
};

say "Then the other";
cmpthese $Iterations, {
    a_then_b => sub { a_then_b($Threshhold + 1) },
    b_then_a => sub { b_then_a($Threshhold + 1) }
};
```

As a final note, to take proper advantage of a ternary the assignment should go on the left-hand-side. The ternary returns the result of its branch.

```
$return .= $line =~ /^-{2,}$/ ? "\N{ZERO WIDTH SPACE}$line\n"
                               : "$line\n";
```

Answer (score 3):

What you may be thinking of is that, in a chain of `if ... elsif ... elsif ... else`, it is most efficient if the tests are written in decreasing order of probability. That minimises the expected number of tests and should result in faster code. But in your case you have only a single test, so it is already sorted, and inverting the logic of that test is irrelevant.

In any case you're worrying about detail much too fine to make any significant difference. You should always write all of your code to be as ***clear*** and ***readable*** as possible

It is only once you have finished writing and debugging your code that you should even consider performance. Most often your run time will be plenty fast enough and, because you have written for readability, it will also be highly maintainable

If your code needs to be optimised then you should start by profiling it to find the bottlenecks. I have ***never*** found inverting the sense of a conditional to be of any use at all. Regardless of the language you're using I would expect the difference between branch and no-branch to be insignificant

I would prefer to see more idiomatic Perl. In addition to reading your file line by line as I wrote in my comment above, I would use the default variable `$_` and add your **zero width space** independently of the rest of the line

```
for ( split /\n/, $content ) {
    $return .= "\N{ZERO WIDTH SPACE}" if /^-{2,}$/;
    $return .= "$_\n";
}
```

Comment: Thx. With your code, wouldn't I lose the EOL? Does split conserves it?

Comment: @Stéphane: I apologise; I'm not near a working PC so I couldn't test my code. It's fixed now, but it would be much simpler if the lines were read in a `while` loop straight from the file handle. As it stands you're making multiple copies of your file.

Comment: my $re = qr/^-{2,}$/o; my $return = join "\n", map { $_ = "\N{ZERO WIDTH SPACE}".$_ if $_ =~ $re; } split(/\n/, $content);

Comment: @JiriKlouda: If you want to offer a solution then you should post your own answer. It's not a legitimate comment on my solution, and code is virtually unreadable in comments. Also, the `/o` modifier has been unnecessary for a long time now, and anyway your regex pattern contains no variables.

Comment: @Borodin I'm not working with a file handle, $content is already a scalar… I wasn't thinking about the order of many tests. I was thinking about the reason why there are likely() and unlikely() functions in C++. In the assembler code, one of the branching costs an additional "jump" (so you'd better use it for the less probable branch)… I was wondering if such consideration could apply to the Perl bytecode.

Comment: @Stéphane Could be, but I'm doubtful. Unlike C++, Perl does not compile down to machine instructions. It has its own opcodes for its own VM. Perl must already jump from opcode to opcode, so there isn't much benefit to optimizing one branch over another. For more information about the internals, see [B::Concise](https://metacpan.org/pod/B::Concise) and [Perl Guts Illustrated](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/RURBAN/illguts-0.49/index.html).

Comment: I added it as a comment as the original poster has asked for performance and to precompile the regex is the only thing you can do for performance short of a C routine embedded through XS. I've included the /o option as I've been working in enterprise and you would be surprise how old version of perl you can find lying around. Your solution was good, just added the map as it can optimize the passthrough of arrays, memory allocation, etc.